# before selector unable vertical-align?

Tags: html, css, sass

Here is my code, I try to make both of my p and before element vertical-aligin in the middle but all failed.

Here is my sass code:

```
   p {
      /*whatever*/          

      &.subtitle {
      vertical-align: middle;
      color: $theme-blue;
      font-size: 1.4rem;

      &:before {
        display: inline-block;
        transform: translateX(-$p-padding);
        content: '';
        height: 50px;
        width: 5px;
        background-color: $theme-blue;
      }
    }
  }
```

can someone help me to do them? Thanks.

btw, is that only block can makes the before sudeo-element show?

Comment: hey everyone i just tried makes :before 
        vertical-align: middle;

Comment: and it works, can someone let me know why?

Comment: Can you show us your HTML code..? Do you want subtitle to be at the vertically center of the particular division..?

Comment: the html is just a   <p class="subtitle">Abastract</p>

Comment: because you have used height

Comment: so if i dont use height, there is nothing, as I tired

Answer (score 1):

For vertical alignment you can try `display:table` and `display:table-cell` property as,

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/SaurabhSonawane/kohsr1bm/1/)

**Your Sample HTML will be**,

```
<div class="subtitle">
    <div class="text">
        <p>Abstract</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Your Sample CSS will be**,

```
.subtitle {
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: table;
    background:#FFF
}

.text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
    display: block;
    text-align:left;
    color: #111111;
    margin: 0px;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:20px;
}

.subtitle:before {
   content: '';
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   height: 50px;
   width: 5px;
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this one, but i think  :before vertical-align: middle; also makes it works, can u let me know why?